# How to add an annotation on distinct items?

Tags: django

I've got a query...

```
packages = Package.objects.annotate(bid_count=Count('items__bids'))
```

Which is supposed to give me a list of packages with the number of bids each. It works great if there's only one item in the package, but if there's more it double counts.

Each package consists of 1 or more items. Each bid is placed on 1 or more items within a package. I want to retrieve the number of bids placed on the items within that package.

If there is 1 bid placed on 2 items within a package, presently this will count as 2, I want it to return 1.

I tried `Count('items__bids__distinct')` but that didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django annotate count with a distinct field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the resolution:

```
packages = Package.objects.annotate(bid_count=Count('items__bids', distinct = True))
```

Comment: There's a `distinct` argument?! I've long since forgotten what I was trying to do with this question, I think that project is abandoned...but if it ever comes up again! This will be handy. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could give you +1000 points.  Nobody on IRC even had a clue how to answer this question,  these kwargs appear to be completely undocumented and the only way to find out they exist is from the source code.

Comment: I spent an hour trying different possible solutions to this! I checked the Aggregate definition in `django.db.models.aggregates.py` and saw the signature `__init__(self, lookup, **extra)`, but then I could not find any docs on how to use those named extra arguments, and of course this is the answer! Why the hell is not this documented!?

Comment: what if we have `distinct('id')` then what will we do?

Comment: Is it only me who occasionally gets `NotImplementedError('annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.')` with similar query?