# Django annotate count with a distinct field

Tags: python, django

I have two models defined loosely like this:

```
class InformationUnit(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    ...

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, in a view, I want to annotate all the `InformationUnit`s that belong to a project, so I do this:

```
p = Project.objects.all().annotate(Count('informationunit')
```

which works just ok.

Furthermore, I want to know, in each project, how many distinct `username`s participate.
That is, count how many distinct `username`s are there in the `InformationUnit`s that compose one project.
I have tried the following, but it simply counts the number of `InformationUnit`, regardless of the `username`:

```
p = Project.objects.all().annotate(Count('informationunit__username')
```

Note that `username` is not an object, it is a string. Is there a clean way to do this or should I create a more complicated code based on loops and spaghetti code :P

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 211, accepted):

`Count` can take a `distinct` argument, like so:

```
p = Project.objects.all().annotate(Count('informationunit__username', 
                                         distinct=True))
```

This doesn't seem to be documented, but you can find it in the source for Count.

Comment: It worked!
I had found this somewhere and even tried it (actually it was the last thing I did before asking the question here). In the beginning it didnt work, but tried it again today after restarting the development server and it did the trick :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is documented (now, anyway): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct

Answer (score 55):

If you just want to count the distinct values, you can use the distinct() and count() functions:

```
count = Project.objects.values('informationunit__username').distinct().count()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. The accepted answer returns a list of objects. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

```
Project.objects.all().annotate(Count('informationunit__username', 
                                     distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 9):

SQL `SELECT field1, COUNT(DISTINCT(pk)) FROM project GROUP BY field1 ORDER BY NULL;`

QuerySet

```
Project.objects.all().values(field1).annotate(count=Count('pk', distinct=True)).order_by()
```