# Django annotate avg with a distinct field

Tags: python, sql, django

I am working on the OpenREM project (http://www.openrem.org). This makes use of the Django annotate functions to efficiently calculate mean values for some of the charts.

In some situations the mean value returned in my development code is incorrect because annotate has counted some items multiple times. This occurs when there are several items associated with the object in question.

To solve this I would dearly love to be able to specify a distinct field to use with the Avg function. I know that something similar is built in to the Count annotate function ([Django annotate count with a distinct field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field)).

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Many thanks for any help or suggestions that you can offer.

Regards,

David

Comment: Can you include an example model and the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at values()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/
You'll want to apply it before the annotation