# How to annotate a distinct Count over multiple relationships in Django?

Tags: django, annotations, django-queryset, django-orm

Given a model that has more than one kind of connection to a related model (I will call the "parent" model), how could I annotate a queryset with a count of parent model objects that are linked through either connection without counting duplicates?

#### Example model definitions

Consider an `Article` model that has 2 links to a parent `Publication` model that are very similar in meaning.

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, related_name='publications')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Publication, related_name='owned_articles')
```

#### Objective

I want to serve a page that is a list of publications. A business requirement is that the number of articles that the publication wishes to take credit for are shown (these publications prefer a generous metric for counting). An article is considered part of the organization if either the "owner" or "publication" field points to it, but no articles should be counted more than once for a single publication. An article may be included in the count of 2 publications if `publication` points to a different object than `owner`.

I don't want to execute a query for every publication in the list.

#### The problem with Count annotations here

`Publication.objects.annotate(Count('publications'), Count('owned_articles'))` would be trivial. Then I will have `count__publications` and `count__owned_articles`.

My problem is that I can't tell how many articles in `count__publications` were also counted in `count__owned_articles`. Django doesn't allow me to cram a full queryset into `Count`, so in this general case of needing extra control of what is counted a special mechanism is needed.

#### Similar questions

I have found this situation most similar to the question here:

[Django annotate count with a distinct field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field)

You could contrive this same general situation by intensifying that question's request by adding another related model in addition to `InformationUnit` and asking for a count of unique usernames among both related models.

Answer (score 1):

(initial answer, answering my own question with a so-so solution)

The preferable approach would be to start with a `Publication` queryset, however, I can manage to squeeze a solution out of the Django ORM by pivoting around the `Article` queryset instead.

Consider as a solution to this problem:

```
exclusive_owners_qs = Article.objects.exclude(
    publication=F('owner')
).annotate(Count('publication')).order_by('publication')

publications_qs = Article.objects.annotate(Count('owner')).order_by('owner')
```

With this, I can loop over the two querysets and add up the 2 numbers locally inside of python to get the correct counts.

This satisfies the requirements, but it's also not an elegant solution. Eliminating the need for a python loop would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer is using `Count("publications", distinct=True)`, as described here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations