# How to count total occurrence of distinct field of same model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get the total count of occurrence of a field in same model in django. Is it possible to do it or not?

for example I have a model as below:

```
class Blog(DateTimeModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

and a table of data as below:

```
 id | title                               | description          | category
----+-------------------------------------+----------------------+----------
  1 | blog title first                    | description 1        | social
  2 | blog title second                   | description 2        | social
  3 | blog title third                    | description 3        | community
  4 | blog title fourth                   | description 4        | community
  5 | blog title fifth                    | description 5        | people
```

I want a result to be as:

```
<QuerySet [{'category': 'social', 'blog_count': '2'}, {'category': 'community', 'blog_count': '2'}, {'category': 'people', 'blog_count': '1'}]>
```

I have tried doing `Blog.objects.values('category').order_by('category').distinct('category').count()` and got result as `3` which is true because it had count the total distinct values related to category.

[Django annotate count with a distinct field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field) this post provide a solution where we can count fields based on two models. But i want the results from the same model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain such queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Blog.objects.values('category').annotate(
    blog_count=Count('pk')
).order_by('category')
```

That being said, the modeling might not be optimal, since it creates a lot of *data duplication*. Imagine if you later want to rename a `category`, then this would result in a huge amount of work, since these categories can be spread over a lot of tables.

It makes more sense to then implement a `Category` model, like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Blog(DateTimeModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
```

Then you can annotate the `Category` objects, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(
    blog_count=Count('blog')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am a little bit confused that if I use a query like `Blog.objects.values('category').annotate(blog_count=Count('pk'))` I get result as `<QuerySet [{'category': 'social', 'blog_count': '1'}, {'category': 'social', 'blog_count': '1'},  {'category': 'community', 'blog_count': '1'},  {'category': 'community', 'blog_count': '1'},  {'category': 'people', 'blog_count': '1'}]>` but when using `.order_by('category')` on last the answer is as expected.

Comment: @dipbazz: that is because if you do not `.order_by(..)`, it will not properly "group by".