# Counting unique (or distinct) values of model field instances with python/django

Tags: python, sql, django, analytics, dashboard

Trying to display a count of unique instances of fields that exist in my database. In the model below, the 'uid' is a user id #, and a user can create multiple records on the database under the same 'uid'. So if i count the number of 'uid's I will simply get the number of ALL records created in the database, **but i am trying to get the number of unique 'uid's that exist in the database.** I have been messing around with .count(), Count, and .distinct() with no luck. I am also quite confused with the distinct=True option. This is in an effort to provide data to an analytics dashboard, so I want to calculate the number of distinct users exist in the database.

**models.py**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    cid = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)  # switched from eid
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class DashboardListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Session
    template_name = 'blog/dashboard.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Session.objects.filter(client=user).order_by('-session_date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_records'] = Session.objects.filter(client=user).count()  # count function
        return context
```

**html tags**

```
{{ total_records }}
```

**example of sqlite database records from model Sessions**

uid | cid | client

001 | abc | DummyCo

001 | abc | DummyCo

001 | xyz | DummyCo

002 | xyz | DummyCo

002 | abc | DummyCo

003 | abc | DummyCo

So the desired output of this would be:

distinct uid's: 3

distinct cid's: 2

(clients will always be the same for this case.)

Just to be clear: I **do not** need a count of how many times '001' was listed as the 'uid', I need to know how many different 'uid's exist in the database.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field?
Have you tried to use `distinct` or `count` chained e.g. `Sessions.objects.values('uid').distinct().count()`.

Comment: Thank you, yes that worked. I saw that question above, but I had trouble applying it to my use since that person was dealing with 2 models and using the ```__```. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @sabiwara, this question has been answered before. I just wanted to put my final code line on here since I had a more simple use case and it might help someone out in the future.

**This is the adjusted views.py part where I added the new code line**

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        session_list = list(context['sessions'])  # evaluates the query
        context['total_users'] = Session.objects.filter(client=user).values('uid').distinct().count() # new code line
        context['sessions'] = session_list
        return context
```

** html tag **

```
{{ total_users }}
```