# Django - How to annotate count() of distinct values

Tags: django, django-orm, distinct-values

I have the following model:

```
class Bank(model.Model):
    name: models.CharField
    ....
```

Using the following sample data:

```
╔══════════════╗
║ Row ID, Name ║
╠══════════════╣
║ 1, ABC       ║
║ 2, ABC       ║
║ 3, XYZ       ║
║ 4, MNO       ║
║ 5, ABC       ║
║ 6, DEF       ║
║ 7, DEF       ║
╚══════════════╝
```

I want to extract distinct bank names like so:

```
[('ABC', 3), ('XYZ', 1), ('MNO', 1), ('DEF', 2)]
```

I have tried using annotate and distict but the following error is being raised:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

I've also come accross the following question on SO:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145254/django-annotate-count-with-a-distinct-field/32653861)

Which has answers on using `models.Count('name', distinct=True)` but it's returning duplicate values.
How can I handle this using Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arakkal Abu's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64383503/8224266) worked for some rows, but was returning some duplicates. I have no idea why, but I added the following to his suggestion:

```
qs = Bank.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('name').distinct()
```

Which made me realize that the exception raised said: **distinct(fields)** is not implemented, not `distinct()`.

Also, on @ruddra's input on using `Count('name')` instead of `Count('id')`, I have not seen the difference between them. They all returned same results.

So the following worked too:

```
qs = Bank.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('name')).order_by('name').distinct()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can GROUP BY query,

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Bank.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('name'))
```

and you will get the result as,

```
[{'name': 'BAR', 'count': 1}, {'name': 'FOO', 'count': 3}]
```

Comment: You should use `count=Count('name')` to get GROUP BY query

Comment: That's a good one, But, is it ***really required***? @ruddra

Comment: This returns duplicate values still. I keep getting: `[{'name': 'BAR', 'count': 1}, {'name': 'FOO', 'count': 3}, {'name': 'BAR', 'count': 1}]`

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt Then, better you use `Count('name')` as @ruddra mentioned.