# Annotation of Similar Article Tags In Django Admin

Tags: django, annotations, tags, aggregate, admin

I want to display similar tags count in the Django admin Tag section like this:

```
name          |      posts
-------------------------------
business      |        3
```

Currently in my Tag table I have something this. This different posts that have similar tags to them.

```
name          |      post_id
-------------------------------
business      |        1
business      |        2
business      |        3
```

My models

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Post Title')

class Tags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Created')
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Last Modified')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Posts')
```

I have this in the admin.py

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'post_count', 'date_created', 'last_modified')
    search_fields = ['name']
    ordering = ['id']
    readonly_fields=('date_created', 'last_modified')
    
    def post_count(self, obj):
        return obj.post_count

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(post_count=Sum("post"))
        return queryset

admin.site.register(Tags, TagAdmin)
```

This is how it looks in the admin panel

```
name          |    post_count
-------------------------------
business      |        3
business      |        3
business      |        3
```

How do I achieve only displaying one instance of a tag name with all the posts that have that tag instead of the repetition above and instead the desired outcome below?

```
name          |      posts
-------------------------------
business      |        3
```

Comment: .Have you tried using return queryset.distinct() ?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145407/4151233 for dinstict counts.

Comment: @JarnoLahtinen some code example expounding in this would be really grateful.